# What is the best calendar pop-up to populate a web form?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to be able to make an HTTP call updating some select boxes after a date is selected. I would like to be in control of updating the textbox so I know when there has been a "true" change (in the event the same date was selected). Ideally, I would call a function to pop-up the calendar and be able to evaluate the date before populating the text box...so I can do my validation before making a server call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JQuery's [datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) is an extremely flexible tool. With the ability to attach handlers prior to opening or after date selection, [themes](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-ui-datepicker-themes), range selection and a variety of other incredibly useful options, I've found that it meets all my needs.

The fact that I sit next to one of its maintainers here at work is also fairly useful...

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing with the jquery datePicker script - you should be able to do everything you need to with this.

Answer (score 2):

[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com/) both have very nice looking and flexible calendars.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever end up considering a JavaScript library/toolkit, [Dijit](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-2-dijit-0), a widget system which layers on top of [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/), has a [calendar](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/test_Calendar.html#) (Dijit calendar test page). I found it relatively simple to implement.

//Disclaimer: I'm in the middle of a love-hate relationship w/ Dojo at the moment, as I am in the process of learning and using it better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the MS ASP.NET ajax, but their datepicker is superb. Otherwise, jQuery datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ASP.NET AJAX Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) or [Steve Orr's drop down Calendar control](http://steveorr.net/articles/DropDownCalendar.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the JSCalendar from Dynarch for a project I'm currently working on. It is LGPL licensed and really flexible (easy to customize to your needs). It has lots of features and looks good, too.

http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/