# Calendar using Javascript/ PHP/ mySQL

Tags: php, javascript, sql, zend-framework, calendar

for a current webapp i need a "outlook-like" calendar... Here are some requirements for the calendar:

- week-view for the appointments
- different appointment types
- direct display of the length and time of the date (like in googleCalendar)
- multiple appointments for the same time
- only using javascript, php and any DB

We need the calendar for the Zend Framework, so if the Calendar doesn't already support the ZF, the source needs to be editable!

do you know any calendar which fits my needs? or do you have any tipps for developing one by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top tip for developing your own calendar: don't. Calendars are *such* a time sink, and non-trivial to write. If you need to ask for tips you'd be better off with an existing library component like you'll find in jQuery, dojo, etc..

This question has been asked many times here, links abound on other questions.

- [Best JavaScript Calendar control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114068/best-javascript-calendar-control)
- [What is the best calendar pop-up for populating a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367/what-is-the-best-calendar-pop-up-for-populating-a-web-form)
- [Creating A Javascript Calendar (Full, not pop up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536999/creating-a-javascript-calendar-full-not-pop-up)

etc, etc...

Comment: hm, yeah... i already recognized that its a extremley time consuming process to develope a calendar and i have read thru many other questions here with the same topic, but i havent found a nice calendar to edit and control events... especially not in the way i need to...

Comment: Your requirements need to be broken down. What you want to do is quite bespoke so it's likely you have to write much of it yourself - but not at the JS end where numerous solutions exist. I'd say find the JS widget you like and work on solving the back end and data input. Ultimately JS is always extensible so that's not going to be your blocker, better to solve the data model problems first.

Comment: Oh and this question seems closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611/designing-a-calendar-system-like-google-calendar

Comment: Hm.. i already read the linked questions and there is nothing too useful... But somewhere in the questions there was the adivce to use the iCal Format for the data. That could be nice.
@annakata: hm.. i think i'll have to do it like you said, right the background by myself and use existing solutions for the JS part and the display of the events...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to say about it, as I've not yet used it, but saw this on Twitter the other day, and I think it may fit at least the Javascript part of the bill.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Its a jQuery calendar, came over Twitter from john resig - who writes jquery.

Comment: Hm, yeah, very nice calendar, but like you mentioned... ity only the javascript part that is really done in that calendar... But that would be a nice base to use!

Comment: Yeah, let me know how you get on if you use it.

I second what the guy below says about time sink too.

Answer (score 0):

One more Outlook-like Javascript calendar that you might consider for your future projects is dhtmlxScheduler. It supports the features you mentioned and comes with the server-side PHP connector, a special layer that manages client-server data connection. dhtmlxScheduler is dual licensed: GNU GPL and commercial.

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

(disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)