# javascript data structure staff matrix

Tags: javascript, date, object, calendar

I want to store how many hours each staff member plans to work each week on each project.

I'm going to populate a table with this data and let the user edit the hours for each week.

I have created objects for each element:

```
//project
function project(name, number, staff)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    this.staff = staff;

}

//staff
function staff(name, date)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.addDate = function(){};
    this.removeDate = function(){};
}

//date
function date(year, month, week, hours)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.week = weed;
    this.hours = hours;
}
```

what is the best way to save and access the hours attached to the date? Is there an example of how to do this somewhere?

Comment: Those are constructors meant to be used with `new`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you asking what is the best way to save and access the `hours` attached to your `date` object? From the way you have it defined, you could simply do things like `myDate = new date(2013, 5, 1, 10);` and then access the hours via `myDate.hours`, and set the hours via `myDate.hours = 20;`. Note that this is poor encapsulation of the date's properties since they are all accessible and modifiable by the client. You should consider using closures so you can hide this information (if that is a desire).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar using Javascript/ PHP/ mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805806/calendar-using-javascript-php-mysql)